# C variable user supplied format strings for snprintf

Tags: c, string

i want to for example make a file like this

```
hello %s
%d seconds more
%d is more than %d
```

where all the format strings are user supplied and will be changed by the program with snprintf.

the problem is if i change the occurrencess of the format strings because `snprintf` use a fixed value of parameters. - the last parameters ...

to understand my idea thats how i want it for example

```
snprintf(dest_buffer, strlen(file_buffer), file_buffer, "user123", 1, 3, 2);
```

if i do one more %s to the file the functions doesent work correctly for sure
cause 3 was last arg to snprintf
can someone provide sample code or ideas to solve this problem

note: file_buffer points to the string "hello %s %d sec ....."
note: i know format strings can dangerous .. thx

Comment: You probably want `sizeof(dest_buffer)` rather than `strlen(file_buffer)` (assuming `dest_buffer` is an array -- you'd want to pass its length at least).

Comment: How does the file specify what variables are to be converted?   Is the "hello %s" to be used with an `snprintf(... some_string)` and "%d seconds more" with `snprintf(... some_int)`, etc?

Comment: i know Ulfalizer i just wrote it quick for you to understand... chux like i said the file will change and the format strings ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two alternatives that I can think of:

1. Write your own string parsing and interpolation (replacement) functions instead of using `*printf()` (or hunt down some third-party library with suitable functions).
2. Use [`parse_printf_format()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-a-Template-String.html) from glibc, which is designed to handle uses like this. This is non-portable, and I don't know what other libc implementations provide similar functions.

Be careful though. This might be easy to get wrong and dangerous as you pointed out. :)

Comment: thx i sought so ... i will have a look at parse_printf_format and or think my way around maybe thx ulfalizer